# How to hide a button/label after x.place()

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am pretty much a python noob so I would appreciate any help with hiding a button/label after it has been placed x.place(x, y)

```
def hide(x):
    x.pack_forget()

def show(x):
    x.pack()

def deliveryback():
    hide(backdel)
    a.pack(padx=30, pady=35, side=LEFT)
    b.pack(padx=40, pady=35, side=LEFT)
    s.pack(padx=40, pady=35, side=LEFT)
    lbl1.pack()
    hide(meat)
    hide(haw)
    hide(pep)
    hide(veg)
    hide(sasa)
    hide(lbl2)
    hide(lbl3)



def delivery():
    hide(a)
    hide(b)
    hide(s)
    hide(lbl1)
    show(backdel)
    show(meat)
    show(haw)
    show(pep)
    show(veg)
    show(sasa)
    show(lbl2)
    show(lbl3)
    backdel.place(x= 500, y=400)
    lbl2.place(x=300, y=200)
    lbl3.place(x=1175, y=200)
    meat.place(x=300, y=375)
    haw.place(x=300, y=460)
    pep.place(x=300, y=545)
    veg.place(x=300, y=630)
    sasa.place(x=300, y=715)
```

If more code is needed I can post it for testing, please do not destroy me for having code that is not needed <3

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I didn't realize `x.place_forget()` existed